# FAB Variable - Unreachable Statement

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am actually trying to create FAB variable:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

But it says

> "Unreachable statement"!

Please note: My Android studio is latest built

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow of code you have written is such that the code that is marked as "Unreachable" will never be executed.

e.g Calling "Return" before the code is reached.

The code you have given in your question is not relevant. It is the code before it that is causing the issue.

e.g

```
private void Test(){
    String x="";
    Return;
    x=3;
}
```

Line 3 will never be run because Return always causes the method to end